# How to get the Pokeflute in Firered and Leafgreen?

Tags: pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

How do you get the Pokeflute in Pokemon Fire Red and Leaf Green

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com.au/) will be able to give your a very detailed walkthrough for all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get it from the caretaker of Pokemon Tower after you finish that area of the game. Use the Silph Scope on the ghost at the top of the tower, fight your way out, and then follow the caretaker to his home to receive the flute.

Comment: Where's the Pokemon tower?

Comment: Lavender Town. Check [this](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_FireRed_and_LeafGreen/Walkthrough) for a list of zones in order of progression.